# Cannot See Design View In Ms Access 2010 Template

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I cannot see design view for forms or tables in the Services template ms access 2010.

In access `options/options/current database/`  the check boxes (enable layout view & enable design changes for tables in Datasheet view)  are both greyed out.

My question is. How can I get into the tables in design mode?
have any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Any web objects do not have a Design View.  Layout view should still be accessible, though, for forms and reports.  Web objects are indicated by a globe in the icon representation of the object.

For web tables, you can only change the design in the datasheet view.  Go to the last column in the datasheet view to add a new column.  That's the only way to change stuff around in web tables.

I do hope that helps!

Comment: I have no idea why they would remove the design view for web tables, but you can still change most of the properties (I just learned this a minute ago).  Click on a field, then go to the Fields ribbon on top.  There you can change the type, add a default value, validation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you copied the template to a suitable location after download and chosen Unblock from Right-Click->Properties? You can also check that the file is not read-only due to other causes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the old shift/open deal? Hold down the shift key, double click the file and keep holding shift until the file is completely opened.

Genius

Comment: I'm going to +1 this comment because this actually worked for me.  Now I remember why I hated Access in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the old shift/open deal? Hold down the shift key, double click the file and keep holding shift until the file is completely opened.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be a "Web Database" there is a way.

1. Create a standard Blank database.
2. Right click each object (Table, Query, Report) and select Export to Access
3. Point it to your Blank database created in Step 1. 
   A. You'll have the option to export the table definition with or without the data.

I admit, it is a little tedious, and possibly could be scripted to make it easier for a lot of objects. I had a small number of objects so it only took about 15 minutes.

Comment: This only seems to work for tables & relationships as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new blank database and import all of the tables, queries reports etc from the old database. This is a lot faster and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Web Database:
 1. The tables can be viewed in design view only by exporting to a standard access Database - or creating a standard database and importing all the tables (and relationships) in one hit. 
 2. The other objects (macros, forms, reports, queries) can't really be  exported or imported as stated by Bobort earlier. The 'web view' doesn't allow design view (forms & reports) or sql view (queries) so it is quite restricting.